# Visual Studio 2015 Memory Usage Tool - Filter by Heap or DLL

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I'm in the process of profiling memory usage for my native application.  When viewing all allocations in a snapshot, is it possible to filter those allocations by module or by a particular heap handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio 2015 memory profiler does not currently support filtering allocations by module. This is something the Visual C++ team is currently looking into providing for a future release.